# Punctuation - comma or not

Tags: punctuation

Is it:
The programs will take place at 9 a.m., 11 a.m. and noon

Or:
The programs will take place at 9 a.m., 11 a.m., and noon

Comment: It depends entirely on what style guide you follow—if you use a serial comma or not.

Comment: Jason's right.  It depends on what style guide you follow.  It's not a question of grammar but a question of style.  The comma in question is an Oxford comma, sometimes called a serial comma.  Whether or not you include it is personal preference unless you are to follow a particular style guide, like that of your employer or university, which style guides always have a position on this and explicitly say whether you are to include it or not.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is for:

The programs will take place at 9 a.m., 11 a.m., and noon.

I prefer the so-called "Oxford comma," as a rule of thumb, because in some instances the lack thereof can result in confusion.